# Location access only from foreground, but google says i use background

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

My app was removed because google says I am using location data from the background.

My app uses a Foreground Service to fetch location data.

I've included

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

there is no Background permission.
I've checked the merged manifest, too. There is no dependency asking for Background permission.

On my device i can't grant location permission for all time, only "While app is running".. So everything looks like expected for me..

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of google support I was able to resolve the issue:

For Android versions < 29 it is not sufficient to remove the Background permission. You have to remove all location listener in the pause method of your activities. With this tiny change, my app is back on google play.